# parse HTTP request from node.js script

Tags: php, json, node.js

I am trying to write a script that will visit a script on `localhost` and parse it in a node.js script. Here's what I got so far:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    port:'80',
    path:'/index.php'
}
var a = http.get(options, function(res){
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    //console.log(res);
});
```

But this is all it returns:
`<Buffer 7b 22 61 77 65 73 6f 6d 65 22 3a 22 79 65 61 68 21 22 7d>`

I know it is some sort of stream but I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the encoding of the response object to one of 'ascii', 'utf8', or 'base64' before adding listeners to it.  For example:

```
var a = http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) { // no longer emits a Buffer object
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

Comment: or just use `chunk.toString()` or `chunk.toString('utf8')`

Comment: @AndreySidorov Doing that can break multibyte characters.